# Is it bad to give money to beggars in India?

Tags: india, beggars

What is the best policy to adopt with regards to beggars in India? Is it ok to give them money/food? If not, are there any charities to which it would be appropriate to give instead?

Comment: [See also](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-to-defend-yourself-from-paupers-in-india)