# Seeing a Bollywood movie in Mumbai?

Tags: india, culture, mumbai, cinema

It looks likely that a group of us will be in Mumbai for a few days in June. We're wondering if there's a really nice cinema (not just a chain) where we can go to watch a Bollywood screening with the local audience experience (cheering etc?)

Comment: Don't just stop there. Mumbai is the home of Hollywood, and its easier for a foreigner to even act in one!

Comment: @AyeshK of course (although you mean Bollywood right?), and we already have a [question on that very topic](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/how-to-become-an-instant-bollywood-actor-while-traveling-through-mumbai?rq=1) ;)

Comment: Sorry, yep Bollywood I meant. Enjoy your trip!

Comment: Book the ticket online. Less hassle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really want to know how lower class and lower middle class people of India watch movies, you can visit **Maratha Mandir** theater. The quality of theater is not that good but it has some history associated with it. It has a record of screening superhit Bollywood movie "Dilwale Dulhaniya Le Jayenge" for continuous 1009 weeks. Unfortunately it doesn't screen the film anymore.

The place is easy to reach. It takes just 5-minute walk from the Mumbai Central railway station.

Answer (score 10):

It really depends on which part of the city you will be staying in. There are many old, single screen theatres in Mumbai, specially in the south part of the city, which is locally called 'Town'. I would suggest that you try one of the following:

1. [Regal Cinema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regal_Cinema):
   [image]

   2. [Eros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eros_Cinema)
   3. New Excelsior
   4. Liberty

Comment: I've been to Eros, and I believe Regal is quite close too. It's a really more like a regular western type cinema, and not the ones one might expect with the local people cheering when the hero enters screen (I can remember one like that in Delhi though).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are still some standalone theatres in Mumbai, such as Regal Cinema, Chandan Cinema in Juhu and Globus Cinema in Bandra. However, it is better to opt for the multiplexes like – PVR, Inox, Cinemax, Big Cinemas.